# Asp.net mvc 3- get the current controller instance (not just name)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I know how to get the current controller name

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
```

But is there any way to get the current controller instance in some class (not in an action and not in a view)?

Comment: Where? In a Model ? In a view ? Of course if you're in an action you can use this to refer to your controller, but I guess that's not the case :).

Comment: in some class (not in an action and not in a view)

Comment: since in MVC pattern you're bound to be in an action, unless you're in some Data Model's method flow or some helper. Just for avoiding null references I'd add a parameter to your class method for the controller, and then tracking where the flow begins and pass it.

Comment: What is that you are trying to do? I don't see any reason why you would like to do so, the controller is there so you can handles requests and that is it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

By default you can only access the current `Controller` inside a controller with `ControllerContext.Controller` or inside a view with `ViewContext.Context`. To access it from some class you need to implement a custom `ControllerFactory` which stores the controller instance somewhere and retrieve it from there. E.g in the `Request.Items`:

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        HttpContext.Current.Items["controllerInstance"] = controller;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

Then you register it in your  `Application_Start`:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

And you can get the controller instance later:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        var controller = (IController)HttpContext.Current.Items["controllerInstance"];
    }
}
```

But I would find some another way to pass the controller instance to my class instead of this "hacky" workaround.

Comment: You should probably change HttpContext.Current.Session["controllerInstance"] to HttpContext.Current.Items["controllerInstance"] since session might end up in the database with certain configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Someone will have to correct me if what I am doing is detrimental to the whole Asp.Net page life cycle / whatever but surely you can do this:

In controller

```
ViewBag.CurrentController = this;
```

In view

```
var c = ViewBag.CurrentController;
var m1 = BaseController.RenderViewToString(c, "~/Views/Test/_Partial.cshtml", null);
```

In my case, I had a base controller that all controllers extend. In that base controller lived a static method called RenderViewToString and it required a controller. Since I figured I could just instantiate a new instance of an empty controller at this point for c, I just sent it to the view in the lovely ViewBag container that exists in the world of Asp.Net MVC. For reasons I could not go into now, I could not retrieve the string in the controller and send just that back to the view (this was what I had done earlier before requirements changed).

The reason  I have done it this way is in other languages like PHP and JS, there are similar simple ways to transfer classes around.