# How to get an instance of the current HttpRequestBase outside of a Controller or View's context

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**What I'm doing:**

I am creating an email mailing engine that takes html templates, replaces tokens with data and then sends off the mail to an SMTP server.  Eventually we'll want a CMS UI on top of this to allow them to add/remove file templates or update the content in them via a CMS UI.  Anyway I am putting the .htm files for the email templates inside my MVC web project and need to read their contents and get the string of HTML back to work with.  If I move all this code out of my MVC project into like a utility C# project layer, the problem is then I have to worry about maintaining physical paths ("C:...\theMVCWebSiteFolder...\Email\Templates\SomeTemplate.htm") and that to me would have to be hard coded I think to keep track if you were to move the site to a different server, different hard drive partition, etc.   So I'd like to be able to work with the files using the current application's context unless there's a way to do this agnostic to my MVC app and still not have to worry about having to ever change the location of the physical root every time we move folders.

I've got the following utility method I created in a utility class that sits in a folder somewhere in my ASP.NET MVC web project in just a folder (a folder outside of any view folders:

```
public static string GetFileData(string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("the file {0} was not found", filePath));

    string text;
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

    using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        text = read.ReadToEnd();

    return text;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why the context is turning up null here.  I originally tried HttpContext.Current but current is coming up null so it can't find the current context in my Utility.cs method that sits in my MVC web project.

UPDATE:

Ok so the consensus is to use HttpRequestBase object and not the HttpContext.Current object.  I still find it weird that the HttpContext.Current is null.  But moving on, if my Utility.cs is outside any context of a controller or view, then how the heck do I get an instance of the current request (HttpRequestBase) to work with and send an instance that implements HttpRequestBase (I do not know what object that would be if I want to do this in the "MVC way" outside a controller or view) to this utility method?

Comment: Is this code running in a handler thread?

Answer (score 2):

No idea why this returns null but since it is a bad idea to tie your business layers with ASP.NET specifics I'd recommend you the following change to your method:

```
public static string GetFileData(string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("the file {0} was not found", filePath));

    return File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

and then when you need to consume it from a web application:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var result = MyClass.GetFileData(Server.MapPath("~/foo/bar.txt"));
    ...
}
```

and when you need to consume it in a WinForms application:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "bar.txt");
    var result = MyClass.GetFileData(filePath);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a utility class I would remove the dependency on any web-related stuff.

For a path relative to the application root I would use:

```
Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, fileName)
```

which will give you what you probably want (a path relative to the web root directory in a web application; relative to the path containing the executable in a WinForms app, ...)

Comment: this is great even though I changed (corrected) the original post.  Sorry but thanks still good info.

Comment: doesn't work because it's pointing to my bin directory for that BaseDirectory value when I try to run this from a unit test: filePath = "C:\\www\\test\\Web.Tests\\bin\\Debug\\Templates\\Header.htm"

Comment: @CoffeeAddict - that's normal.  To make it accessible during unit testing, you need to deploy the relevant files.  The following link is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If want to rewrite that method in asp.net mvc way, you could rewrite it this way and remove coupling with `HttpContext` class

```
public static string GetFileData(HttpRequestBase request, string filePath)
{
    if (!File.Exists(request.PhysicalApplicationPath + filePath))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(String.Format("the file {0} was not found", filePath));

    string text;
    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);

    using(StreamReader read = new StreamReader(fileStream))
        text = read.ReadToEnd();

    return text;
}
```

And generally in MVC `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` are abstracted into `HttpContextBase`, `HttpRequestBase` and `HttpResponseBase` accordingly

Comment: How does that remove coupling with the `HttpContext` class? It just changes where you get the reference to it from. This would, for example, still be unable to be used in a WinForms application.

Comment: sorry to ask this but how the heck do I get an instance of HttpRequestBase to send into this if I am not in an MVC controller where I'd be able to get it right there?  I've looked it up but can't find anything about how to grab an instance of that in an MVC app.  OI'

Comment: @AndrewBarber he wrote - "that sits ASP.NET MVC web project:". I thought that means this class is inside MVC. And he edited his question, he was asking about HttpContext usage in first version :). Of course this cannot be used in non-mvc apps

Comment: yea my original post was wrong.  So I corrected it.  This class does sit inside my MVC web project.  Utility.cs in one of my folders.  Originally I said it was outside, my fault.

Comment: yea so just trying to figure out now how to get the current request in an mvc app so I can pass that into the HttpRequestBase param.

Comment: @archil Your answer starts off by saying, "*remove coupling with HttpContext class*", but your code does no such thing. `HttpRequestBase` requires `HttpContextBase`. The code is *still coupled*.

Comment: maybe I can do this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865598/asp-net-mvc-3-get-the-current-controller-instance-not-just-name

Comment: Every controller in asp.net mvc has inherited Request property, that is type of HttpRequestBase. So you can call this method as var data = GetFileData(Request, path);

Comment: My code and logic won't be in a controller.  My Utility class is just a straight C# class so how does it know about the request?  This code is being called to send out emails...has nothing to do with the Views or needed up at that layer or in controllers.  This is an email send engine I'm creating and just happen to put the code in my MVC project under a folder...but eventually this will need to be a UI as I'll be building a CMS around this so allow some people to edit all the email templates, content; at some point my web project will need to work with the raw request outside a controller

Comment: @AndrewBarber yes, id does. But abstract HttpContextBase is not sealed HttpContext or I am missing something very obvious. In mvc controllers, implementation of HttpContext property is type of HttpContextWrapper, not HttpContext

Comment: @archil Look at Darin's answer; see how his `GetFileData` has *no* web-related code in it whatsoever? Your code is requiring an object that is only available in a Website project. Not only that - it's code that is only available in an MVC project. The code is still tightly coupled to a *web project*, with server DLLs. And yes - `HttpContext` is still in there! `HttpContextBase` is something different that comes via MVC - but the original ASP.NET `HttpContext` is still there whenever you have `HttpContextBase`

Comment: @AndrewBarber we are actually talking about same stuff. I know that! :). And I know this code is not to be used without mvc. As I told you and as I remember, when I wrote this answer, question was about using HttpContext in mvc - so I answered how to correctly use HttpContext in asp.net mvc way. If you think this answer should be removed, I can do that, no problem :)

Comment: @archil It's bad design to have a library dependent upon the application layer. That bad design is actually *what's causing the trouble in the first place here*, more than likely. And you actually haven't done what you say you've done; If there's an `HttpRequestBase`, there's a `HttpContextBase`, and if there's a `HttpContextBase`, there's a `HttpContext`. You've hidden the coupling by a couple layers of abstraction, but it's still there.

Comment: Yo people I'm still in the dark.   My file is in an MVC app but the code being called (this filepath) is NOT in my controller or views so how the hell do I get this request context then if it's just vanilla C# code in a standard .cs in an MVC project???  is this about separation of the HttpContext (which I agree is also important) or my question here?  I'll keep working on this in the meantime but can't figure out how to get an instance of the current request outside controller/views in an MVC app.

Comment: I understand what Andrew is getting at and he's right.  Yea I should really move this whole Utility.cs out to our Utility C# project in which I have a place for putting this method in the first place!  Good point.  It doesn't belong in my MVC app.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict what is the problem to do as Darin answers?

Comment: Now that I think of it though only one problem with making this method agnostic to a web app.  I don't want to have to specify the whole filepath on the server meaning the drive letter, etc.  I want to reference the filepath relative to the my web app root via virtual path not physical path.  So I think this one does make sense to keep here in my web app afterall.  If I need an agnostic utility method then I can go create that later on for whatever other purpose outside this web app.  So Darin what's your response to that!

Comment: So I noticed I can use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request if you wanna put it in a non-web layer (project).  For some reason I had to fully qualify the type because putting a using statement to System.Web did not work in my utility method that I now took outside my web project..not sure why.

As to the null HttpCurrent, still have that problem in the other utility method I mentioned that is in my mvc project