# How to get current controller instance in another class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

In my project I manage exception in a class like this

```
 public class PortalBusinessExceptionManager
    :IBusinessExceptionManager
{
    public void HandleBusinessException(BusinessExceptionDto exceptionDto)
    {
        //TODO
    }
}
```

And I have a `BaseController` in my project that all controllers inherit from it

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void SetNotification(string message, ExceptionType type)
    {
       //TO DO
    }
}
```

So I want that in `HandleBusinessException` method how can I get an instance from current controller and invoke `SetNotification` for it

```
 public void HandleBusinessException(BusinessExceptionDto exceptionDto)
{
    var controller=....???
     controller.SetNotification(); 
}
```

Comment: why are you trying to use controller as class object

Comment: @SatpalSingh I want Invoke SetNotification method in my exceptionmanager class

Comment: Your controller shouldn't have logic like this.  You're on the cusp of discovering [Onion Architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/), and should look into what a service layer is, and how it should be used to [keep your controllers thin](http://www.codemag.com/article/1405071).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865598/asp-net-mvc-3-get-the-current-controller-instance-not-just-name) you can create your own `ControllerFactory` and put the controller instance in the session for later retrieval.

```
public class MyControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["controllerInstance"] = controller;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

Then you register it in your Apllication_Start:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

And you can than call the instance in your exception handling method.

```
public void HandleBusinessException(BusinessExceptionDto exceptionDto)
{
     var controller= HttpContext.Current.Session["controllerInstance"] as BaseController;
     if(controller != null) 
     {
         controller.SetNotification(); 
     }
}
```

Note that this is a pretty hacky solution (session may expire for example and your method wont be called), you should probably be better off overriding `OnException` method in your `BaseController` and call `SetNotification` there

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    public void SetNotification(string message, ExceptionType type)
    {
       //TO DO
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        SetNotification(filterContext.Exception.Message, yourExceptionType);
        base.OnException(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do people downvote? At least care to explain, I will always accept arguments. I am starting to feel that people do this on purpose.

Comment: @Valipour `HttpContext.Current` itself is not thread safe. It's a static singleton. Moreover, `Session` is not safe to use because it's a per-user, per-session storage mechanism, and doing something like this may prevent your controller object from being disposed properly across many requests. This is a bad answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it solves your issue yet it can be helpful:

```
// get current controller instance
var controller = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<MyController>();
// pass current request context
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(Request.RequestContext, controller); 
// call method
controller.MethodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to put in de HttpContext.Items insted Session